# WrapGrid horizontal scroll Windows 8

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-runtime, horizontal-scrolling

I have next XAML for main grid:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="NewsListBox">
            <ListView.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF006C67" Opacity="0.5"/>
            </ListView.Background>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
```

And it looks nice, how it is needed:

**But it doesn't scroll the content!**

[image: Example]

Ok, i add ScrollViewer:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ZoomMode="Disabled">
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="NewsListBox">
            <ListView.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF006C67" Opacity="0.5"/>
            </ListView.Background>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

And it stacks everything vertically:

[image: Example]

**What am i doing wrong?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution. No ScrollViewer is needed.

Just had to replace ListView with GridView because ListView isn't designed for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Actually, you can change the behaviour of the ListView so much to be like GridView. It mostly has to do with customizing the ItemsPanelTemplate. They even use the same resources for styling.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<ListView
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
>
```